# Cargo el contenido de un .php que contiene un form en un div pero no funciona submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Es la primera vez que escribo, ya que casi siempre encuentro la respuesta solventada sin tener que explicarla antes.

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

Tengo un **index.php** con un div para cargar una lista de usuarios en la parte superior y otro en la inferior donde se cargan los datos de la fila que yo seleccione en el div superior a través de otro php.

El caso es que cuando listo por ejemplo una lista de usuarios y pulso en una fila para cargar abajo sus datos completos, me los carga perfectamente pero no me funcionan los botones de los formularios, no hace el envío al archivo de destino del formulario ***action="archivo.php"*** , pulso en el botón submit y no hace nada.

```
    function ajaxFunction() {
var xmlHttp;

try 
{  
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
return xmlHttp;
} catch (e) 
{

try 
{
  xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  return xmlHttp;
} catch (e) 
{

   try 
  {
    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return xmlHttp;
  } catch (e) 
    {
    alert("Tu navegador no soporta AJAX!");
    return false;
    }}}
    }




function Enviar(_pagina,capa)
{
var ajax;
ajax = ajaxFunction();
ajax.open("POST", _pagina, true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajax.readyState==1){
        document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML = " Aguarde por favor...";
             }
    if (ajax.readyState == 4) {

            document.getElementById(capa).innerHTML=ajax.responseText;

         }}

ajax.send(null);
```

Ese es el código ajax para enviar un **.php** a un div concreto , dicho php contiene lo siguiente:

```
echo "

            <table>
                <th colspan='20'><form action='listarusers.php' method='post' name='busco'><input type='search' style='margin:9px;background-color:white' name='busqueda'placeholder='Buscar aqui...'autofocus size='100' ><input type='submit' name='buscar' value='Buscar'/>
                </form></th>
                <tr>
            <th colspan=3>El usuario no existe, ¿deseas crearlo?<th><tr>
            <th colspan=3></th><tr>

            <th>Cuenta</th>                                     <th>Datos personales</th>                                       <th>Datos de contacto</th><tr>
            <form action='add.php' method='post' onsubmit='return validar(this);'>
            <td><label>Nombre usuario: </label><label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Nusuario' value='' required/></label><br>
            <label>Contraseña: </label><label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Password' value='' required /></label><br>
            <label>Fecha registro: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Fregistro' value='".date('Y-m-d')."' /><br>
            <label>Nivel membresia: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Nivelmembresia' value='1' /><br>
            <label>Rango: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Rango' value='USR' /><br>
            <label>Activado: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Activado' value='0' /><br>
            <label>Premium: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Premium' value='0' /><br>
            </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <label>Nombre: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Nombre' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Apellidos: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Apellidos value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Genero: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Genero' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Fecha nacimiento: </label><input type='text' size='' id='cal_".$contador++."' class='txt' name='Edad' value='2000-07-30' /><br>
                                                        <label>Direccion: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Direccion' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Ciudad: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Ciudad' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Provincia: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Provincia' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>CP: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Cpostal' value='' /><br>
                                                        <label>Pais: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Nacionalidad' value='España' /><br>
                                                    </td>
                                                                                                                <td>
                                                                                                                    <label>Email: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Email' value='' /><br>
                                                                                                                    <label>Telefono: </label><input type='text' size='' class='txt' name='Telefono' value='' /><br>
                                                                                                                </td><tr>
            <td colspan='3'><center><input type='submit'  style='margin-left:px;' alt='Añadir' value='Añadir' /></center></td><tr>";
```

El caso es que no funciona el formulario, aprietas en el de añadir o en el de actualizar y no hace nada.

Me pasa lo mismo con un calendario en jquery, si cargo el **php** a pelo funciona todo formularios y submits pero si lo cargo dentro de un div con la funcion de **ajax** no trabajan.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. La pregunta no se entiende bien. Deberías siempre llamar las cosas por su nombre cuando preguntes, así será más fácil ayudarte. Por ejemplo, en vez de decir que llamas a `archivo.php` debes decir qué archivo llamas, si es `listausers.php` o si es `add.php`... Debes explicar también cómo funciona la lógica del programa, cuáles son las funciones que manejan los eventos submit del formulario, etc. Nada de eso es claro. En uno de los formularios veo esto: `onsubmit='return validar(this);` pero luego no veo ninguna función `validar` en el Javascript que compartes.

Answer (score 0):

Vale, conseguí solucionar el problema: los formularios no se estaban generando bien por la forma en la que estaban puestos dentro de la tabla.

Los formularios con sacarlos de la tabla ya funcionan.

Comment: Si esto es una nueva pregunta deberías crearla en [crear nueva pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y no mediante una respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo no entendi del todo bien tu pregunta la parte del calendario pero prueba enviando junto con el php un script para que haga el trabajo, espero me entiendas algo asi.

```
boton.click(functio(){
    Form.submit();
});
```

Suerte...